# android: convert canvas to bitmap then save to SD card

Tags: android, android-canvas

i'm developing an android app where I can draw on a canvas. I want to convert my canvas to bitmap and then save it in jpeg format on my sd card..

how can i properly do this?

Answer (score 5):

Something like that should work :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache(boolean)

```
public void toJPEGFile(){
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder/");
    if(!folder.exists()) folder.mkdirs();

    try {
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder/file"));
        Bitmap bitmap = this.getDrawingCache();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Comment: You should free up the memory when you are done with the bitmap, using `bitmap.recycle()`

Comment: What is folderAppointment? I get a nullpointer because I don't have anything like that declared/

Comment: Hm this code is really old. I think it is a spelling mistake, just replace folderAppointment by folder.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look up the documentation?

[Canvas API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)

You can use the:

```
public Canvas (Bitmap bitmap)

    Since: API Level 1
    Construct a canvas with the specified bitmap to draw into. The bitmap must be mutable.
    The initial target density of the canvas is the same as the given bitmap's density.
    Parameters

    bitmap  Specifies a mutable bitmap for the canvas to draw into.
```