# Can we save canvas as an Image to sd card in Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am working with `Canvas` in Android Studio, have **.png image** on canvas and want to save it to sd card. Is it possible? 
if yes then how?

thanks and regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android: convert canvas to bitmap then save to SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962374/android-convert-canvas-to-bitmap-then-save-to-sd-card)

Comment: - Create a Bitmap
    - Get a Canvas for the Bitmap
    - Draw with the Canvas into the Bitmap  
    - Save the Bitmap

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you ([Saving canvas to bitmap on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001455/saving-canvas-to-bitmap-on-android))

```
Bitmap toDisk = null;
        try {

            // TODO: Get the size of the canvas, replace the 640, 480
            toDisk = Bitmap.createBitmap(640,480,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas.setBitmap(toDisk);
            toDisk.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File("arun.jpg")));

        } catch (Exception ex) {


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have created Canvas with new Canvas(myBitmap);. So when you draw on the Canvas, it draws to your bitmap.

```
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.png";
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
/* Write bitmap to file using JPEG or PNG and 80% quality hint for JPEG. */
myBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
stream.close();
```